# Interface result delphi to c# - class define dll use in c#

Tags: c#, delphi

I have a class define in dll. I export this class by interface. I use this dll and class in other Delphi project very good but I want use this class in c# but send error for me.

Source DLL:

```
type
  IMyDate = interface
    ['{D032F796-167D-4B0D-851D-2AEEA226646A}']
    Procedure Analyze_Date(var y:Integer; m,d:Integer); stdcall;
  end;

  TMyDate = Class(TInterfacedObject, IMyDate)
  Public
    Procedure Analyze_Date(var y:integer; m,d:Integer); stdcall;
  End;

procedure TMyDate.Analyze_Date(var y:Integer; m, d: Integer);
begin
  y:= m+d;
end;

Function MyDate:IMyDate; stdcall;
begin
  result:= TMyDate.Create;
end;

exports
  MyDate;
```

Unit use in Delphi example:

```
Function MyDate:IMyDate; stdcall; external 'Project11';

implementation

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  md:IMyDate;
  var y,m,d:Integer;
begin
  md:= MyDate;
  y:=10;
  m:=20;
  d:=30;
  md.Analyze_Date(y,m,d);
  showMessage(intTostr(y));
end;
```

Use in c# but get error:

```
//[Guid("D032F796-167D-4B0D-851D-2AEEA226646A")]
public interface IMyDate
{
    void Analyze_Date(ref int y, int m, int d); 
}

[DllImport(
"Project11.dll"
, EntryPoint = "MyDate"
, SetLastError = true
, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall
, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IMyDate MyDate(); 

private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int y, m, d;
  IMyDate da;
  da = MyDate(); // get error this line
  y = 10;
  m = 20;
  d = 30;
  da.Analyze_Date(ref y, m, d);
}
```

**Update**

thank you for answer

i add new function to Interface and class but my function only return false

also my function and procedure in delphi is stdcall and interface in C# is normaly !!!

```
IMyDate = interface
['{D032F796-167D-4B0D-851D-2AEEA226646A}']
Function testing():Boolean; stdcall;
end;

TMyDate = Class(TInterfacedObject, IMyDate)
Public
Function testing():Boolean; stdcall;
End;

function TMyDate.testing(): Boolean;
begin
result:= true;
end;
```

c#:

```
[ComImport, Guid("D032F796-167D-4B0D-851D-2AEEA226646A"),
 InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IMyDate
{
    bool testing();        
}

[DllImport(
      "Project11.dll"
      , EntryPoint = "CreateMyDate"//"MyDate"
      , SetLastError = true
      , CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall
      , CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]    
public static extern void CreateMyDate(out IMyDate Date); 

    Boolean b;

    b = da.testing();  //this line only return false
    if (b)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ffff");
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell us the error?

Comment: Might be nice to tell us the error... just sayin'... if you want help.

Answer (score 5):

The first issue I see is that Delphi's binary interface for function return values is different from that used by C# (and indeed every other major Windows compiler).

So instead of using a function, use an `out` parameter.

```
procedure CreateMyDate(out Date: IMyDate); stdcall;
begin
  Date := TMyDate.Create;
end;
```

Then on the C# you can declare the function like this:

```
[DllImport(@"Project11.dll")]
public static extern void CreateMyDate(out IMyDate Date);
```

Note that I removed a load of spurious parameters to your `DllImport` attribute. I guess you were adding them at random!

The other issue is the interface. It needs to be declared as being a COM interface that supports `IUnknown`. Like this:

```
[ComImport, Guid("D032F796-167D-4B0D-851D-2AEEA226646A"), 
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IMyDate
{
    void Analyze_Date(ref int y, int m, int d); 
}
```

**Update 1**

The first problem with the updated question is something I failed to pick up in my original answer. The way the C# interface is declared means that that the marshaller assumes that the native functions all return `HRESULT` COM error codes. If the C# method has a return value then it is implicitly converted into an `out` parameter. There is a simple way to achieve this in Delphi. You replace `stdcall` with `safecall` on each method in the interface, and obviously in the implementation of that interface. Note that you should not change the calling convention of the `CreateMyDate` function.

So your Delphi code should be like this:

```
IMyDate = interface
  ['{D032F796-167D-4B0D-851D-2AEEA226646A}']
  Function testing():Boolean; safecall;
end;

TMyDate = Class(TInterfacedObject, IMyDate)
Public
  Function testing():Boolean; safecall;
End;
```

Another problem with the method in updated question is that C# marshals `bool` as a 4 byte value, but Delphi `Boolean` is just a single byte. This error is actually benign, but you can fix the problem by making the two sides of the interface match. For example:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
bool testing();
```

And I repeat what I said above. I removed spurious parameters from your `DllImport` attribute. In particular don't use `SetLastError` because your code is not setting the Win32 last error. Your `DllImport` should be exactly as per my answer. Don't confuse things by adding needless extra parameters to the attribute.

**Update 2**

You say in comments that you can't use `safecall` on the Delphi side. Which means that you need to suppress the `HRESULT` signature transformation on the C# side of the interface. That's done with [`MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.preservesigattribute.aspx). You need to apply it to each method on your C# interface.

```
[ComImport, Guid("D032F796-167D-4B0D-851D-2AEEA226646A"), 
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IMyDate
{
    [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig)]
    void Analyze_Date(ref int y, int m, int d); 

    [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    bool testing();  
}
```

This interface matches up with a Delphi interface declared like this:

```
IMyDate = interface
  ['{D032F796-167D-4B0D-851D-2AEEA226646A}']
  procedure Analyze_Date(var y: Integer; m, d: Integer); stdcall;
  function testing(): Boolean; stdcall;
end;
```

Comment: hi
thanks for answer and comments
but if I whant change Interface delphi for Exaple:
    IMyDate = interface({IUnknown}IInvokable)
    ['{D032F796-167D-4B0D-851D-2AEEA226646A}']
    Analize_Date(var y:integer; m,d:Integer); stdcall;
    end;
and define procedure by Stdcall but i dont now how Define this Interface in C#?

Comment: I'm surprised to see mixing P/Invoke and COM invocations in a Delphi  C# interop scenario. Usually it's one or the other.

Comment: @j. It allows you to expose an OOP like thing without full blown COM.

Comment: @David. Thanks for clarifying. Though I have to say, it still don't understand the benefits of the mixe vs. following traditional ways of handling this type of issue. Is it performance related or something else I'm missing?

Comment: thanks 
but i edit source by
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
bool testing();    
but return False
also my Interfce in delphi must be Stdcall and cannot use safecall
i dont now

Comment: Why can't you use safecall? It's trivial to change it. Or do you have other clients of that interface.

Comment: hi david
yes my project have meny dll and all proc is stdcall and other project use this DLL

Comment: And if I solve this latest problem, are you going to ask more and more in comments? I'm just saying that this is not a free support service. It's meant to be simple Q&A. I've answered two questions in one now. This is the third question. You really should stop. I'll look at it because I'm curious, but are you going to stop tacking on new questions to the end of this one?

Comment: OK, I've solved it. Will update the answer in a second. I hope this will satisfy you!

Comment: ok very thanks david for all answer
i very try in C# to Resolved my problam

Comment: I'm sure this works. When you are also sure, please do come back and accept the answer.

Comment: You aren't doing it right. If you do exactly what I said, then it will work.

Comment: Ifdo exactly what you said, but it no work and always return FALSE.
i dont now

Comment: after the pate code update 2 function always return TRUE and if change the Dll Delphi to return False but in c# you get True !!!

Comment: Nope, works fine here. I can't imagine what's wrong. Here's a pastebin of my test project: http://pastebin.com/ei1Hyb32  Please run this exact code. It's known to work. Please don't even consider for a minute doing anything other than cut/paste from that code to your compilers.